# Can I set a formula for a particular column in SQL?

Tags: sql

I want to implement something like Col3 = Col2 + Col1 in SQL.

This is somewhat similar to Excel, where every value in column 3 is sum of corresponding values from column 2 and column 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do it in SQL using the UPDATE command:

```
UPDATE TABLE table_name
SET col3=col1+col2
WHERE <SOME CONDITION>
```

This assumes that you already have a table with populated col1 and col2 and you want to populate col3.

Comment: You can also do it in a SELECT statement - it doesn't have to be just part of an UPDATE

Comment: and actually, storing a calculated value usually breaks normalization rules

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at [Computed Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx)

> A computed column is computed from an
>   expression that can use other columns
>   in the same table. The expression can
>   be a noncomputed column name,
>   constant, function, and any
>   combination of these connected by one
>   or more operators.

Also from [CREATE TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) **point J**

Something like

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.mytable 
( low int, high int, myavg AS (low + high)/2 ) ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Provided it is not aggregating data across rows.

assume that `col1` and `col2` are integers.

```
SELECT col1, col2, (col1 + col2) as col3 FROM mytable
```